# XNA 2D windows phone level editor

Tags: xna, windows-phone

Can anyone kindly point me in the right direction as to what the best way is to make a 2D Level Editor in XNA for Windows Phone?

I have a game that's almost finished but I wish to create multiple versions of it in the future with different levels and themes etc.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest not making one and using something like [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) instead. It will save stages in a relatively simple XML format, and there's even a [C# library](https://github.com/marshallward/TiledSharp) to read the Tiled files.

There are plenty of other good editors as well. I recommend going in this direction because quite frankly you will spend way too much time making your own.

To expand further on Tiled, you can use [the aforementioned library](https://github.com/marshallward/TiledSharp) to parse a TMX file, which are made from using Tiled and saving your map. Read the **Usage** on the github page, looks pretty simple to use.

When you parse a Tiled element, say a specific tile index or a Tiled "object", you have to map that to something useful in your game (a graphical sprite texture, an enemy or object the player can interact with, etc.). For tiles, you can manage this via `enum`s (create an alias for each tile type and assign it the exact tile number from your tilesheet), or even just an array that follows the same mapping. For objects, use Tiled's object properties to assign meaningful values that you define, which then get saved along with the TMX and you can parse them using that library.

For example, you could define a property in a Tiled object called "enemytype" and give it the value "lizard". The code when parsing could look for this property and value, and create a `Lizard` object when it's parsed.

Comment: Hmm, this is pretty much what i've been looking for. Thank you very very much. I hope it integrates nice and easy with Windows Phone!

Comment: It does, I made a WP7 game utilizing Tiled, which is why I recommended it :)

Comment: Can you share a link please of the game?

Comment: What were the steps you took to make the map in Tiled and then get it imported to WP?

Comment: Awesome stuff. I'll have a go at this very soon :) Thanks a lot for your help Scott.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a nearly-finished game, then I'd assume that somewhere in there is code to load and display the map you have. Extract that code and you're halfway there. Then you just need to add some way of adding to the map it's reading from, and save it back to the same format.

If your maps are currently created in memory, then you'll need to figure out a file format you can save them as (XML or JSON works, but a big CSV of ints for tile types works too and is simpler). Then you'll need code to read in from that format and populate your current map model.